# SQLAlchemy multiple joins to single table

Tags: python, join, flask, sqlalchemy

I am making a wishlist app and I want to have db schema like bellow, but I can't figure out how to make the joins in sqlalchemy (this is the first time I am using sqlalchemy).

[**DB schema**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww3q6.png)
(**user : wish = 1 : N**)

When I select a user, I want to get a list of wishes and each wish may contain a different user (an arranger of the wish)

So I could do something like this

```
first_user = User.query.get(1)
user_wishes = first_user.wishes.all()

for wish in user_wishes:
    if wish.arranger is not None:
        print(wish.id, wish.owner.id, wish.arranger.id)
    else:
        print(wish.id, wish.owner.id)
```

I have looked up some tutorials, but I only found simple relations.
I need a relation from *User* to *Wish* and in the *Wish*, back to both the *UserWishOwner* (the user from which I got here) a *UserWishArranger* (if there is any).

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wishes = db.Column(db.relationship('Wish', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic'))

class Wish(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)
    arranger_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)

    arranger = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[arranger_id])
```

I have come up with some code, but am a bit confused, because `owner_id` and `arranger_id` are the same...

What do I need to do, to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    wishes = db.relationship('Wish', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic', foreign_keys="[Wish.owner_id]")

class Wish(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)
    arranger_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)

    arranger = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[arranger_id])
```